# Dynamiclly append different class with increment numereic value by click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span tag and a button tag

```
<span class="myspan">1</span>
<button id="add">Add +1</button>
var arr=["myspan1","myspan2","myspan3","myspan4"}
```

I want to append more span tag with new class from  this array with increment value by clicking button.
Like this output:

```
<span class="myspan1">1</span>
<span class="myspan2">2</span>
<span class="myspan3">3</span>
<span class="myspan4">4</span>
```

i  try `
[this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2XG2/4/)

But i can not add class name to new append tag from array.

Another useful link for appending tag with new class from array
http://jsbin.com/nojipowo/2/edit?html,css,js,output
...
But i can not bring my desire output at any case...enter code here

value increaseesenter code here this snippet

```html
<script>    var i = 0;    function buttonClick()    {i++;     document.getElementById('inc').value = i;    }    </script>    <button onclick="buttonClick();">Click Me</button>    <input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>
```

another attempt...anyone can help.. to get desire output

```js
var i=6;
var backgrounds = ["myspan1", "myspan2", "myspan4"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myspan");var len = backgrounds.length;

$("#add").click( function() {
(i < elements.length){


  $(".new-field").append('<span class="myspan">1</span><script');
    var value = parseInt($(".myspan").text(), 10) + 1;
    elements[i].className += ' ' + backgrounds[i%len];
    i++;
    $(".background").text(i);    
    }
});
```

```css
*/
```

```html
<span class="myspan">1</span>

<button id="add">Add +1</button>
<div class="new-field">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>    var i = 0;    function buttonClick()    {i++;     document.getElementById('inc').value = i;    }    </script>    <button onclick="buttonClick();">Click Me</button>    <input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this check the span length via `parseInt($(".myspan").length)` .And use with [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwich6KOoqnUAhVBPY8KHR5IBRQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNHYjVYqeuypZH7lxBPKNG7LM-OBOg&sig2=2QOa7-jD6zdSFHRCuq-VlQ) for iterate the array instead of increment `i`.`parseInt`  used convert ths string to number

```js
var i=6;
var backgrounds = ["myspan1", "myspan2", "myspan4"];

var len = backgrounds.length;

$("#add").click( function() {
var len = parseInt($(".myspan").length)
backgrounds.forEach(function(a){
  $(".new-field").append('<span class="'+a+'">'+(len++)+'</span>');
    })
    console.log($(".new-field").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myspan">1</span>

<button id="add">Add +1</button>
<div class="new-field">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/T2XG2/155/). Hope this helps!

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mainContainer"> 
<span class="myspan">1</span>
</div>
<button id="add">Add +1</button>
```

**JS :**

```
var arr = ["myspan1", "myspan2", "myspan3", "myspan4"];

$("#add").on("click", function() {
var spans = $("span");
var classList = [];
$.each(spans, function() {
    var elemCls = $(this).attr('class').length > 1 ? $(this).attr('class').split(' ') : $(this).attr('class');
    if (elemCls) {

        $.each(elemCls, function() {

            classList.push(this.toString());
        });
    }
}); 
$.each(arr, function(i, e) {

    if ($.inArray(e, classList) == -1) {

        $("#mainContainer").append("<span class='" + e + "'>" + parseInt(spans.length + 1) + "</span>");
        return false;
    }
});
});
```